# locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid Debian Buster

Tags: mysql-workbench, debian

Problemas al abrir un archivo de modelo de BD hecho en `mysql workbench` este esta instalado en debian 10 Buster la ultima versión e intentado con este comando:

```
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" mysql-workbench
```

Sin embargo da el mismo error alguno tiene una solución o algun otro programa capaza de hacer lo mismo que hace `mysql-workbench`
[image]

Agradeceria la ayuda  a  este gran problema que se me a presentando

Answer (score 1):

Dando y dando a los problemas que tenia con este diseñador de Base de datos realice lo siguiente en mi terminal asi de una vez solucinando dicho problema, espero les sea de ayuda

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get install locales
echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen
locale-gen
```

Comment: Thank you saved my day !